# Looking for smallest number

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the smallest number where you can enter as many number and when you enter -1 it breaks.

```
a=int(input("What is your number of choice? "))
b=int(input("What is your number of choice? "))
c=int(input("What is your number of choice? "))
d=int(input("What is your number of choice? "))
smallest=a

if (b < smallest):
    smallest=b
    while(True):
    smallest =int( input("What is your number of choice? "))

    if (smallest == -1):
       break
if (c < smallest):
    smallest=c
    while(True):
    smallest =int( input("What is your number of choice? "))

    if (smallest == -1):
       break
if (d < smallest):
    smallest=d
    while(True):
    smallest =int( input("What is your number of choice? "))

    if (smallest == -1):
       break
print(smallest, " is smallest of the numbers you chose")
```

I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: any reason you're not using the `min` function?

Comment: a '-' character is not an integer

Comment: How can you get this exception in function min, if you use function int() for all the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a loop to allow the user to enter multiple values. keeping track of these values can be done using a list, and appending each input to it as follows:

```
all_inputs = []
val = int(input('Enter a number (or -1 to finish):'))

while val != -1:
    all_inputs.append(val)
    val = int(input('Enter a number (or -1 to finish):'))

print(str(min(all_inputs)) + ' is the smallest of your numbers')
```

`min` can efficiently find the smallest value input.

Comment: Thank-you so much for the help. I greatly appreciate it because I've been struggling for so long with it.

Comment: You're welcome! Be careful though - it'll break if someone types in anything but a number!

Answer (score 0):

If `c` is smaller than `b` and `b` is smaller than `a` you never reach the `c<smallest` code because you enter into the previous while bucle.

Also you need to indent correctly your code.

```
if (b < smallest):
    smallest=b
    while(True):
        smallest =int( input("What is your number of choice? "))

        if (smallest == -1):
            break
```

Finally break is exiting out of the method without executing the las print line.